# MySQL Deprecated

Tags: php, mysql

Ao inserir dados em uma tabela aparece a seguinte mensagem:

Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\EasyPHP14.1\data\localweb\projects\phptest\conexao.php on line 3

Estou utilizando somente um código básico para testar o ambiente de desenvolvimento que estou utilizando (EasyPHP).

Comment: Essas funções estão depreciadas e foram removidas do php7, você precisa trocar pelo MySQLi ou PDO.

Comment: Por favor, considere pesquisar se a solução já existe no site.

Comment: Se você colocar um @ antes da função o warning não é dado. MAS NÃO FAÇA ISSO, já que vai aprender procure por MySQLi ou PDO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A própria mensagem já diz o problema: as funções `mysql_*` foram descontinuadas. Então, como descontinuada, ela já está obsoleta e nas versões futuras do PHP, as funções `mysql_*` provavelmente serão removidas.

Como alternativa, você deve usar `mysqli_*` ou `PDO`.

Caso queira mais detalhes, recomendo a leitura dessa pergunta: [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%c3%a3o-devemos-usar-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-do-tipo-mysql) onde temos excelentes respostas.