# UPDATE de informaçoes banco de dados

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho uma tabela, onde existe um campo chamado (PAGAMENTO), o valor padrao dele é "PAGAR".

[image: Banco de Dados]

Fiz o seguinte codigo, para alterar o VALOR "PAGAR" para "PAGO"

```
$results = "UPDATE snaps SET Pagamento='PAGO' WHERE id= 27";
```

Porem, ele só funciona, para 1(um) ID de usuário, queria saber como faço para melhorar esse codigo, para quando eu executar ele, ele pedir o código do usuario(id) , ao invez de ter um ID já pre-definido no caso o "27".

Obrigado a todos que ajudam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$id_form` vindo de um  [formulário](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp), podendo ser method Post ou GET

Exemplo de method Post:

```
<form method="post" action="PAGINA_DESTINO">
   <input type="number" name="id"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

**PAGINA_DESTINO**

```
$id_form = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * snaps where id= '$id_form'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $id= $row['id'];
}

//O update  
$results = "UPDATE snaps SET Pagamento='PAGO' WHERE id= '$id'";
```

OBS: Use mysqli ou PDO [MySQL Deprecated](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102326/mysql-deprecated/102329#102329)